# Constrain when create table mysql failure

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php with mysql and I would like to restrict the user input to certain value. For example Type should be M or C only but not others. Therefore i use the code as following to create a table1 under database hactl.

```
/**********************************************************************/
/*Create database and table*/

CREATE DATABASE Hactl;
CREATE TABLE  Hactl.table1(
    Type VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Region VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Imp DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Exp DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    TS DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Year INT(4) NOT NULL,
    Month VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT chk_hactl CHECK(Type IN ('M','C') AND
                   Month IN ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 
                         'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                         'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep',
                         'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
                  )
);
```

While when i insert a new row with Type = K, it still can insert successfuly.

Comment: You can use enum and set this field as NOT NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rescrict other entry, you can simply use `ENUM`

```
CREATE TABLE  Hactl.table1(
Type enum('M','C') NOT NULL,
Region VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
Imp DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
Exp DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
TS DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
Year INT(4) NOT NULL,
Month enum('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 
           'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
           'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep',
           'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec') NOT NULL,

);
```

Comment: i notice for attribute Type, you did not put char(1). Char(1) statement is no longer meaning, right?

Comment: In `ENUM` we dont need to put `char`

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Patel, what if i wanna set number range like 1-10. Thanks again.

Comment: You can use same concept, as 1 to 10 is not larger range. you can put it in `ENUM`. Other than that, by means of programming you can always do any kind of validations.

Comment: what if it is range 223 to 956. how can i achieve that?

Comment: To check certain range of numbers, you need to use `CHECK` or you can validate it in PHP as well. But, `mysql` doesn't support `CHECK`. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25660 . You can use trigger instead. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

`CONSTRAINT ... CHECK` is not valid syntax in MySQL. See documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Syntactically you can use a `CHECK` clause in a `CREATE TABLE`, but all MySQL storage engines simply ignore it as not supported. Note this comment `The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.` from this page in the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Typically this sort of data validation is enforced via use of `ENUM` field type. See documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html